# Vlcj on Raspberry Pi get exception "UnsatisfiedLinkError"

Tags: java, raspberry-pi2, unsatisfiedlinkerror, vlcj

I run my file java on Windows it work perfectly, but run on Raspberry Pi i get exception UnsatisfieldError. please help me fix it, thank you!

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/jna-pi/jna3395684713782359103.tmp: /tmp/jna-pi/jna3395684713782359103.tmp: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibraryFromJar(Native.java:771)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadNativeLibrary(Native.java:697)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.<clinit>(Native.java:127)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.<clinit>(NativeLibrary.java:62)
    at StreamingServer.Streaming.run(StreamingServer.java:88)
```

Comment: Did you provide the native files ? You need different ones on Linux than on Windows. What is in the /tmp/... directory, can you see any .so files there ?

Comment: tks for reply @Marged
no .so file in /tmp directory.
when i build my project on netbean, native file included in "lib" directory, same place with .jar file